# Activating existing virtual environment in WSL

Tags: python, virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a beginner in the process of learning Python.

I have created a virtual environment and usually I activate it in Window Power Shell using the command

```
ll_env\Scripts\activate
```

Recently, I installed Windows Subsystems for Linux and tried to activate my existing virtual environment in it, but it failed.

The commands that I tried:

```
ll_env/Scripts/activate
```

But that gives me an error message:

```
ll_env/Scripts/activate: line 3: $'\r': command not found

ll_env/Scripts/activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'l_env/Scripts/activate: line 4: `deactivate () {
```

I also tried:

```
source ll_env/Scripts/activate
```

But that gives me the error message:

```
: command not found

-bash: ll_env/Scripts/activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'bash: ll_env/Scripts/activate: line 4: `deactivate () {
```

I also tried:

```
source ll_env/bin/activate
```

But it gives me the error message:

```
-bash: ll_env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

How can I activate the virtual environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a virtualenv made on the Windows side of the fence in WSL, since the interpreters (and of course the operating systems too) are different.

You'll need to recreate the virtualenv using the Python interpreter within your WSL (Linux) environment. (Happily, of course, you can name that virtualenv e.g. `ll_env_wsl`, so both can live side by side.)

Comment: I am installing the WSL in order to use Platform.sh to try deploy my project, in this case, is it required to recreate the virtual env and activate it in WSL?

Comment: Possibly. Creating your virtualenv should be a matter of `python -m venv ...` and simply installing your dependencies from your `requirements.txt` or similar (you do have one, right?), so it's not a big hurdle.

Comment: Yes, I have the file. I will recreate the virtualenv. Thank you~

Comment: If you check the Windows environment you'll notice that the installed tools are the windows versions (python.exe, pip.exe etc), and `activate` contains the Windows path of the environment, eg `VIRTUAL_ENV="c:\Projects\MyProject\.venv`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not to mention any binary libraries, etc., if any, would be for Windows.

Comment: I am new to WSL (and Python) and there are many things that I don't know. Thank you very much for the explanations.